# STM8S Discovery : Button Logic Issue

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, stm8, iar

I am making a project where in I am connecting few LEDs with my STM8 Discovery Board (PA3, PD3, PD4) and setting the mode using the on-board button (PB7). The issue I am facing is that I am able to toggle to Flag = 2 (with for loops for phasing the 3 LEDs) but the button becomes unresponsive after that. I need to be able to go back to Flag 0 and Flag 1.

I am a beginner so there is a lot of hit & trial that I have done but the code is doing what it is supposed to do except this part. Would appreciate any guidance on this pls.

TIA!

```
#include "STM8S.h"
 
 
void clock_setup(void);
void GPIO_setup(void);
void ADC1_setup(void);
void TIM2_setup(void);
void Key_scan(void);
 

unsigned int A0 = 0x0000;

int i = 0;
  

int flag = 0;

void delay_ms(long n)
{
  while(n--> 0);
}
 
void main()
{
   
   clock_setup();
   GPIO_setup();
   ADC1_setup();
   TIM2_setup();
   //ITC_setup();
  
   
   while(TRUE)
   {
     
    Key_scan();
      
   
   }

}
  
void clock_setup(void)
{
   CLK_DeInit();
                
   CLK_HSECmd(DISABLE);
   CLK_LSICmd(DISABLE);
   CLK_HSICmd(ENABLE);
   while(CLK_GetFlagStatus(CLK_FLAG_HSIRDY) == FALSE);
                
   CLK_ClockSwitchCmd(ENABLE);
   CLK_HSIPrescalerConfig(CLK_PRESCALER_HSIDIV1);
   CLK_SYSCLKConfig(CLK_PRESCALER_CPUDIV1);
                
   CLK_ClockSwitchConfig(CLK_SWITCHMODE_AUTO, CLK_SOURCE_HSI, 
   DISABLE, CLK_CURRENTCLOCKSTATE_ENABLE);
                
   CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_SPI, DISABLE);
   CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_I2C, DISABLE);
   CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_ADC, ENABLE);
   CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_AWU, DISABLE);
   CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_UART1, DISABLE);
   CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_TIMER1, DISABLE);
   CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_TIMER2, ENABLE);
   CLK_PeripheralClockConfig(CLK_PERIPHERAL_TIMER4, DISABLE);
}
  
 
void GPIO_setup(void)
{
   GPIO_DeInit(GPIOB);
   GPIO_Init(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_MODE_IN_FL_NO_IT);
                
   GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA);
   GPIO_Init(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_MODE_OUT_PP_HIGH_FAST);
                
   GPIO_DeInit(GPIOD);
   GPIO_Init(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_MODE_OUT_PP_HIGH_FAST);
   GPIO_Init(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_MODE_OUT_PP_HIGH_FAST);

   
   GPIO_DeInit(GPIOB);
   GPIO_Init(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_MODE_IN_FL_NO_IT);
   
}
 

void TIM2_setup(void)
{
      TIM2_DeInit();
      TIM2_TimeBaseInit(TIM2_PRESCALER_32, 1000);
      TIM2_OC1Init(TIM2_OCMODE_PWM1, TIM2_OUTPUTSTATE_ENABLE, 1000, 
                   TIM2_OCPOLARITY_LOW);
      TIM2_OC2Init(TIM2_OCMODE_PWM1, TIM2_OUTPUTSTATE_ENABLE, 1000, 
                   TIM2_OCPOLARITY_LOW);
      TIM2_OC3Init(TIM2_OCMODE_PWM1, TIM2_OUTPUTSTATE_ENABLE, 1000, 
                   TIM2_OCPOLARITY_LOW);
      TIM2_Cmd(ENABLE);
}

 
void ADC1_setup(void)
{
   ADC1_DeInit();         
                
   ADC1_Init(ADC1_CONVERSIONMODE_CONTINUOUS, 
             ADC1_CHANNEL_0,
             ADC1_PRESSEL_FCPU_D18, 
             ADC1_EXTTRIG_GPIO, 
             DISABLE, 
             ADC1_ALIGN_RIGHT, 
             ADC1_SCHMITTTRIG_CHANNEL0, 
             DISABLE);
                                                                                  
   ADC1_Cmd(ENABLE);
}
 
void Key_scan(void)
{
  
  if(GPIO_ReadInputPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7) == 0)
  {
    do
    {
    }while(GPIO_ReadInputPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_7) == 0);
    //delay(10000);
    delay_ms(1000);
    
    if(flag > 2)
    {
      flag = 0;
     
    }
    else 
    {
     flag = flag + 1;
    }       
  }
  
       if (flag == 0)
     {
       TIM2_SetCompare1(0);
       TIM2_SetCompare2(0);
       TIM2_SetCompare3(0);
     }
     
     if (flag == 1)
     {
        ADC1_StartConversion();
       while(ADC1_GetFlagStatus(ADC1_FLAG_EOC) == FALSE);
                                
       A0 = 200 * ADC1_GetConversionValue();
     
       ADC1_ClearFlag(ADC1_FLAG_EOC);
       
       delay_ms(50);
       TIM2_SetCompare1(A0);
       TIM2_SetCompare2(A0);
       TIM2_SetCompare3(A0);
       delay_ms(50);       
          
    }
     
    if (flag == 2)
     {
          
       for(i = 0; i < 3000; i += 1)
          {
              TIM2_SetCompare1(i);
              delay_ms(100);
          }
                
          delay_ms(10);
       
          for(i = 0; i < 3000; i += 1)
          {
              TIM2_SetCompare2(i);
              delay_ms(100);
          }
          delay_ms(10);
                  
          
          for(i = 0; i < 3000; i += 1)
          {
              TIM2_SetCompare3(i);
              delay_ms(100);
          }
          delay_ms(10);
          
          for(i = 3000; i > 0; i -= 1)
          {
              TIM2_SetCompare1(i);
              delay_ms(100);
          }
          delay_ms(10);
          
          for(i = 3000; i > 0; i -= 1)
          {
              TIM2_SetCompare2(i);
              delay_ms(100);
          }
          delay_ms(10);
          
          for(i = 3000; i > 0; i -= 1)
          {
              TIM2_SetCompare3(i);
              delay_ms(100);
          }
          delay_ms(10);
      
    }
  
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried running the TImer and ADC setup again in the if(flag>2)? Maybe your button code is working but your Timers and ADC are off? Just a guess.

Comment: Is flag == 3 an allowed state? Because you test for > 2, then add 1 so it will happen. >= will allow 0,1,2

Comment: So if I remove all the delay functions in the flag = 2 part, the button runs as expected but I cant phase LEDs slowly as I require. Is there another way to phase the LEDs like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qMwAmZ-RUAg